# useMemo vs useEffect for ThemeProvider

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created ThemeProvider component where it retrieves the design tokens from json which is passed in as `tokens` prop, then it inserts those tokens into style attribute of parent div. And ThemeProvider wraps the children component so children can use those styles. Since consumers won't be updating tokens often, I just need to run the retrieveToken function once in the initial render.
My question is should I use useEffect with empty dependency or should I be using useMemo to cache the result of retrieveToken function? My guess is useEffect with empty dependency is enough since token prop won't be updated at all, only needed for initial run.

```
const [tokenObj, setTokenObj] = useState({});
const {tokens} = props;

function retrieveToken(tokens){
// expensive operation, but only needed to run once in initial render
}

//which way is better?

// Option1 - react useMemo
const tokenObj2 = React.useMemo(() => {
    return retrieveToken(tokens);
},[tokens]);

//Option2 - react useEffect
React.useEffect(() => {
    setTokenObj(retrieveToken(tokens))
},[])

return (
    <div style={tokenObj}> {children} </div>
)
```

Comment: Is `retrieveToken` synchronous or asynchronous?

Comment: it is synchronous

Comment: Then use `useMemo` and avoid having to render twice. (setting state in your useEffect will cause the component to rerender)

Comment: When I console.log inside of useEffect, I notice it logs once, but if renders twice then I should see 2 logs, no?

Comment: If your log statement is in the useEffect, then that only tells you how many times the effect ran, not how many times the component rendered. Move the log statement to the body of the component.

Comment: I see the log twice now. You are right. So if function is asynchronous then you suggest, I use `useEffect`? Why is that?

Comment: Yes, if it's asynchronous you would use a useEffect. That's because it's the only option. You must render once to get things started, but rendering is always synchronous. So you do your async work after the render in a useEffect, wait for it to complete, and then set state to render again.

Comment: Nevermind my previous answer. I misread the requirements. `useMemo` is the right one to use since you don't need an "only once" semantic guarantee.

Answer (score 0):

`useMemo` is the right one to use and is purpose made for running expensive synchronous operations less often.

`useEffect` should not be used for a few reasons:

- It is primarily there for handling async logic as a pattern
- It is not executed during Server-Side Rendering
- It runs after the DOM is rendered (users will briefly see the wrong styles)